# How do I reference an html dropdown list via a button function?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In my Razor page I have this:

```
<label for="tentacles">Seleccione opción:</label>
        <select name="opciones" id="list">
               <option value="demo">Demo</option>
               <option value="demo2">Demo 2</option>
        </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()>Conectar</button>

@code {

private void myFunction {

(I need an instance variable here? in that case, how?)

}
```

As you can see, I have an HTML dropdown list and I intend to make it work with a button event, the question is how do I reference it from that function... I'm new in C#...

I know that in Javascript it's referenced with getElementById, but in this case, how would it be?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your requirement? Can you elaborate what you are trying to do here?

Comment: As I said in my post I'm trying to reference -the select html- from the button's function and I don't know if I have to use an instance variable for example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At risk of asking a potentially condescending question, but do you know the difference between server-side code and client-side code? Remember that all Razor/`.cshtml` does is generate _opaque text_ (which just-happens-to-be HTML) to the remote web-browser, so it's not possible to "reference" a rendered HTML element (which is ultimately just text) inside Razor. Also, are you thinking of the (ancient and obsolete) ASP.NET WebForms framework that had "server-side events"? (If so, that framework isn't in ASP.NET Core anymore for various reasons)

Comment: @Dai Yes I know the difference but I wasn't sure about you say because I have razor pages where it shows me the visual HTML content (Tables, buttons, checkbox, for example). I guess the issue of references is another story, but thanks, I'll have it consider.

Comment: What do you mean by "visual HTML content"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using blazor,here is a working demo for blazor:

```
<label for="tentacles">Seleccione opción:</label>
<select name="opciones" id="list" value="@Opciones" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => Opciones = __e?.Value?.ToString())">
    <option value="demo">Demo</option>
    <option value="demo2">Demo 2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="myFunction">Conectar</button>
@code {
private string Opciones { get; set; }="demo";
private void myFunction() {

(I need an instance variable here? in that case, how?)

}
```

When `select` changes value,`Opciones` value will be changed,and if you want to get select value in `myFunction()`,you only need to use `Opciones`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have full context of what do you want to achieve, but this is how you can get instance of select

```
<select @ref=@mySelect name="opciones" id="list">
    <option value="demo">Demo</option>
    <option value="demo2">Demo 2</option>
</select>
```

Then in code behind

```
@code{
     private ElementReference mySelect;

     private string Opciones { get; set; }="demo";

     private void myFunction() {
        //  here you can get reference for select in mySelect
     }    
}
```